Does materiality address both discretionary and mandatory criteria for a benefit under 8 U.S.C. § 1182(a)(6)(C)(i)?
Many immigration benefits such as adjustment of status, change of status etc. are discretionary benefits i.e even if the immigrant national has met the objective eligibility criteria, the decision to grant the benefit is in the hands of the DHS. On the other hand DHS cannot deny a petition based on an exercise of discretion arbitrarily or capriciously. They have to weigh the positive and negative factors on the record such as family ties, history of employment/unemployment, violations of immigration laws, misrepresentations to the Government whether they be material or immaterial etc.
The statute 8 U.S.C. § 1182(a)(6)(C)(i) reads -

Any alien who, by fraud or willfully misrepresenting a material fact, seeks to
procure (or has sought to procure or has procured) a visa, other documentation, or
admission into the United States or other benefit provided under this Act is
inadmissible.

My question is would harmless willful misrepresentations such as date of birth or address become material in another proceeding where the grant of the benefit is discretionary?
The Supreme Court in Kungys vs U.S. ruled that a misrepresentation is material if it has a natural tendency to influence the decisions of the government i.e. they were predictably capable of influencing the decision of the government.
The Board of Immigration Appeals (BIA) came up with its own test of materiality in Matter Of D-R- (2017) in line with Kungys i.e. misrepresentation "tends to shut off a line of inquiry that is relevant to the alien's admissibility and that would predictably have disclosed other facts relevant to his or her eligibility for a visa, other documentation, or admission to the United States.”
Would discretionary factors such as harmless immaterial misrepresentations become material in another proceeding where the grant of benefit is discretionary? Does the statute sweep so broadly that it includes discretion as well?

I think it was Justice Kagan who raised the prospect in a case a few years ago of lying about one's weight.  Wouldn't the materiality depend on the specific misrepresentation?

So basically, you are asking whether misrepresentation of an immaterial fact can be considered a negative factor in the adjudication of a discretionary benefit?

@user102008 I am asking if an immaterial misrepresentation becomes material in another proceeding where the grant is discretionary such that even though standing alone the fact has no consequences with regards to eligibility for the benefit but because the lie was repeated in another proceeding it becomes material. Is that possible? I do agree that it is a negative factor for discretionary purposes but does the statute consider eligibility AND discretionary factors as well?

@emily.neumann.immi.atty: What you're saying doesn't make sense to me. The only thing you've quoted that contains the word "material" is in the ground of inadmissibility for fraud or misrepresentation of a material fact (one of many grounds of inadmissibility). But inadmissibility and discretion don't mix -- if you are inadmissible, you will definitely be denied and discretion is not involved, so discretion is only relevant when there are no grounds of inadmissibility. How then does the term "material" come up in discretion? You have not quoted anything that involves "material" and discretion.
